# Android execution error in AVD

Tags: android

an anyone look at this simple code (?) and tell me what's wrong please?
I'm a complete beginner to android development and I don't understand why my application doesn't even start. I get an unexpected error.. : (
Here it is:

```
package applicationTest.ppr.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
public class MainClass extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    /*Global vars*/
    public static LinearLayout lila;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lila = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lilay);
        setContentView(lila);
    }

    public void Shortoast(){new Game(this);}

    public static LinearLayout returnLayout(){return lila;}


}
```

The program doesn't even launch, and I think it might have something to do with how I handle the LinearLayout and setContentView();

anyway thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Do you have layout xml file which defines your R.id.lilay?  Try to use:  setContentView(R.Layout.yourlayout)

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: yes, i have it in my main.xml, although the main reason I tried this approach was because i want to update some text to the screen from another class. That's why I created the returnLayout method. so that I could do something like MainClass.returnLayout().setView(texView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: keep it as simple as possible until you fix the issue!
Then you can concentrate on your business logic.

```
package applicationTest.ppr.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainClass extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id.lilay);
    }

}
```

Also, is your main activity mapped in the Android manifest?

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name="MainClass"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>

</activity>
```

--EDIT--
Do you have the lilay.xml file in your res/layout folder?

Comment: lilay is my linearlayout ID, if it was an xml file shouldn't it be R.layout.NAME.xml?

Comment: Well.. i just figured out that I'm not using linearlayout correctly...
my goal is to have some text on screen. and also a button. when the butotn is pressed, that text is altered, without creating a new object...